# JSON result of PHP is not showing how I expect

Tags: php

I have following problem:

I have this code simplifyied:

```
$contents = $pdo->query($sql);
$results = $contents->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach($results as $row) {
    $string = htmlspecialchars($row['content']);
    array_push($all_matches, array("data" => $string, "id" => $row["page_id"]));
}

echo json_encode($all_matches);
```

And in my database I have following content for example:

```
<h1>MRG Beispiel Seite</h1>

<h2>Ein Beispiel für Einbindung einzelner Felder / Strings aus dem Impressum-Modul:</h2>
```

And my result is following:

```
[{data: "", id: "8"}]
```

My `page_id` displays but not my content, it stays blank, how do I fix this?

The query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `cms_page` WHERE page_id = 8";
```

When i do `echo $row["content"]` it actually shows me some content, its a string. The problem is the `echo json_encode("data" => $row["content"]` its blank

SOLUTION:

I fixed that problem by encoding my string to UTF-8 with:

```
echo json_encode(utf8_encode($row["content"]));
```

Comment: Just to make things totally clear please show us the query

Comment: Please show an excerpt of your database. Like a screenshot.

Comment: Do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE cms_page;` and copy/paste the output to your question

Comment: var_dump($row); exit; what do you see?

Comment: i will do this tomorrow in the office, thanks for help

Comment: What you need to do is figure out where the data is going missing. To do this you can narrow it down with `echo` or `print_r/var_dump` commands. For example: after getting the results do a `var_dump($results);`. Inside your foreach do a `var_dump($row);` also do a `var_dump($row['content']);` and a `var_dump($string);` You will then be able to track down where the error is coming from. Are you sure that your database field is called `content`?

Comment: i am 100% sure that the database is filled with content, when i do that command in phpmyadmin it actually show some result, only on the php side it doesnt

Comment: Instead of `utf8_encode`, you should set your database connection encoding to UTF-8 to ensure your database already returns UTF-8. You also shouldn’t HTML-encode the data before putting into JSON, it’s superfluous and is just mangling the data.